# Mysql result manipulation

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, left-join, group-concat

I have one big mysql query and it shows one column results as below.
[image]

Now I want to count each individual entity in visit_type. How can I do that ?

Results :

[image]

I don't want any other sql query. I want that things happen inside my main query :

```
     SELECT DATE( `fc`.`date` ) AS Date,`f`.`name` AS facility_Name, count( * ),
    `fc`.`provider_id`, CONCAT( `u`.`fname`, ' ', `u`.`lname` ) AS 
    provider_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT((`oc`.`pc_catname`)) AS `visit_type` 
    FROM `form_encounter` AS fc 
    LEFT JOIN `facility` AS f ON ( `fc`.`facility_id` = `f`.`id` )
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON ( `fc`.`provider_id` = `u`.`id` ) 
    LEFT JOIN `openemr_postcalendar_categories` AS oc ON ( `fc`.`pc_catid` = `oc`.`pc_catid` ) 
   WHERE DATE(`fc`.`date`) BETWEEN '2016-06-17' AND '2016-06-24' 
  GROUP BY `fc`.`facility_id`, DATE( `fc`.`date` ),provider_name 
  ORDER BY DATE( `fc`.`date` ) ASC
```

Any help greatly appreiciated.

Comment: @Jens: OP uses `group_concat()`, so he did not store it like this

Comment: @juergend I was just going to ask about that.  Then the query posted isn't what generated the results.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I think it is. OP outputed just the one relavant column results of `GROUP_CONCAT((oc.pc_catname)) AS visit_type`

Comment: Yes, I have displayed only one column result because I want in that only modification

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with two levels of aggregation.  Something like this:

```
SELECT Date, facility_Name, Provider_Id, Provider_Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pc_catname, '(', cnt, ')')
FROM (SELECT DATE(fc.`date`) AS Date, f.name AS facility_Name,

             fc.provider_id, CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname)  AS provider_name,
             pc_catname, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM form_encounter fc LEFT JOIN
           facility f
           ON fc.facility_id = f.id LEFT JOIN
           users u
           ON fc.provider_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
           openemr_postcalendar_categories oc
           ON fc.pc_catid = oc.pc_catid 
      WHERE DATE(fc.`date`) BETWEEN '2016-06-17' AND '2016-06-24' 
      GROUP BY fc.facility_id, DATE(fc.date), provider_name, pc_catname
     ) x
GROUP BY facility_id, date, provider_id, provider_name
ORDER BY DATE(fc.date) ASC;
```